# SharePoint 2013 calculated column text functions like FIND() SEARCH() don't work when site's regional settings locale is set to Swedish

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, calculated-columns

SharePoint 2013 calculated column text functions like `FIND() SEARCH()` don't work when site's regional settings locale is set to Swedish (or any language other than English).

*For Eg:* the simple formula given below for calculated column works with English locale and not with Swedish locale.

```
=FIND("CO", This is a CO group")
```

Any Idea how to make this work with Swedish Locale?
Any help Appreciated ....

Answer (score 0):

You need to express the formulas in the specific language.
FIND, in Swedish, becomes then HITTA 
http://office.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows-sharepoint-services-help/find-function-HA001160996.aspx

You also need to be careful that separator within the formula, as well as quotation, may differ from English formulas.
Separator can be ';' rather than ','
Quotes within the formula may need to be single (') rather than double quotes (")